# Php in "regions" without php filter

Tags: blocks, theming

I've heard that using the php filter is dangerous. Something about having php in databases being a bad practice. I use it in blocks quite a bit and want to move away from that.

I have a lot of page template files so I need a replacement for regions/module_invoke blocks. I tried using an include but dealing with paths was tedious. Is that the only option or is there something easier?

Comment: Have you looked at panels, context or display suite? All give you a rich way to determine entity inclusion, such as blocks, via a UI your advanced users can manage, without needing to know PHP.

Comment: @Screenack I've heard of them, but I'm trying to keep using contrib modules to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Includes or requires is likely your best bet here, why are they tedious? If the includes are within the same theme/template files directory you needn't use absolute paths.

If you cannot use relative paths then you can use `getcwd()` to get the current path/working directory of a file, or use `drupal_get_path()` to get the path to a theme or module file.